# Ionic FileChooser: File Upload Name Error

Tags: file, ionic-framework, file-upload, ionic3, angular-file-upload

I'm working on a Ionic project. And I've to upload a file from the android storage. I'm using Ionic native [FileChooser Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/). The issue is that the function is returning me the uri as :

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1112
```

While actually the file I selected was named 'sample.pdf'. So the Uri should have been like below:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/sample.pdf
```

But this is not the case!!

Here is the code->

```
this.fileChooser.open()
        .then(uri => {
          debugger;
          console.log(uri);
})
```

I also tried resolving the uri using function *resolveNativePath(uri*), but no solution.  What's wrong here?

Comment: I guess it has to do with **the android version**. The device in which I'm live loading/testing/running my app has **Oreo 8.1** and after digging up a bit, got to know that there are some changes in the storage format. Hence the issue. AFAIK, Ionic has not yet updated the plugin / documentation to suit this change.

However it is worth noting that, **if I rename the file** name I selected earlier then it rightly shows the name instead of 1112.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the *File* plugin requires the absolute path of the file to read but the *File Chooser* plugin returns a **URI** 
and so using `resolveNativePath` will actually assist you, you could try:

```
nativePath: any;

 getNativePath () {
   this.fileChooser.open().then((url) => {
   this.filePath.resolveNativePath.resolveNativePath(url, (result) => {
    this.nativePath = result;
    this.uploadImage();
   }
  )
 })
}  

uploadImage() {
     this.file.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.nativePath, (res) => {
      res.file((resFile) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
        reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
          var imgBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg'});
          //Upload the file
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Here we use the [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/), [FileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/) and [FilePath](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/) Cordova plugins

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. Let me elaborate in a bit more detail. The uri returned by FileChooser is `'content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1112'`, so even if I use 'resolveNativePath' it throws error as: `Cannot Resolve Native File Path Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/1112`. The file response that I get on this uri using 'resolveLocalFilesystemUrl' is as : `"{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"1112","fullPath":"/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1112","filesystem":"<FileSystem: content>","nativeURL":"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1112"}"` 
But once if I rename the document I get uri from FileChooser as `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Fsample.pdf`. It is in this case that **resolveNativePath** resolves the path to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.pdf`.